# How can I filter skills in Twilio Flex Team View page

Tags: reactjs, filter, flexbox, twilio, listener

How can I filter the skills list on the Twilio flex team view page? I need to filter the skills based on the worker role. I can detect the role from worker attributes. But how can I filter the skills displaying in team view when clicking on agent name at Twilio flex. I don't want to display all skills, I want to display some of them.

[image]

Or, is there any listener that I can use to detect when that panel is opening? In that situation, I can filter the skills view using the DOM selector.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I don't have a good answer for you, I'm afraid, as that's a bit further into Flex than I've managed to go. However, I have some ideas.

You can listen for a worker to be selected in the supervisor view using the [Actions Framework](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/actions) [`SelectWorkerInSupervisor` action](https://assets.flex.twilio.com/docs/releases/flex-ui/1.27.0/Actions.html#.SelectWorkerInSupervisor) (you can listen to `beforeSelectWorkerInSupervisor` or `afterSelectWorkerInSupervisor`.

The thing I'm not sure about is how to actually filter the skills. I was looking at [this filtering plugin for inspiration](https://github.com/twilio-professional-services/plugin-queues-view-filters) but I couldn't quite tell what was going on. I wonder if you can affect the state in redux based on your currently selected worker.

Sorry, this isn't a full answer. Hopefully it gives you some ideas though.